# Encoding an array with JSON; getting "illegal offset type" error

Tags: php

I am trying to use a getJSON method in jquery to retrieve a dynamic array.  I am getting an "illegal" offset error trying to encode my dynamic array.  Here is the server side code (I am confident the javascript is correct because when I remove the query it runs fine):

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once "database.php";
db_connect();
require_once "auth.php";
$current_user = current_user();
include_once("config.php");

$westcoast_id = $_GET['westcoast_id'];

$westcoast_array = array();


 $query = "SELECT city, state FROM users GROUP BY city";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

if($row['city'] != '' && $row['state'] != '') {
    $westcoast_array[$row] = "location:".$row['city'].", ".$row['state'].", stopover:true";


   }

}

$data = array($westcoast_id, $westcoast_array);

echo json_encode($data);


?>
```

The illegal offset is in reference to the line:

```
$westcoast_array[$row] = "location:".$row['city'].", ".$row['state'].", stopover:true";
```

I cannot see what the issue is.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: `$row` is an array. How is it supposed to work as a *key* for another array?

Comment: Absolutely nothing to do with json. this is purely a PHP problem - you're using an incorrect array key inside your fetch loop, exactly as @DCoder is pointing out above.

Comment: It also looks like your json will have issues.  Using a comma in the location value without enclosing it in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $westcoast_array[$row] = [...]
```

is wrong. (you cannot use an array as a key)

Simply use:

```
$westcoast_array[] = [...]
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  This was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
if($row['city'] != '' && $row['state'] != '') {
    $westcoast_array[] = "location:".$row['city'].", ".$row['state'].", stopover:true";
}
```

or

```
if($row['city'] != '' && $row['state'] != '') {
    $westcoast_array[$row['state']][$row['city']] = "location:".$row['city'].", ".$row['state'].", stopover:true";
}
```

And then you can use `var_dump($westcoast_array)` to see the structure.